# Bloqueo de pantalla devExpress

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

Buen día! Tengo una ventana con dos paneles, uno de búsqueda y otro con un grid que muestra resultados deacuerdo a los valores seleccionados. Esta ventana cuenta con controles devExpress. El tema es que cuando dejó de interactuar con la ventana unos 10 minutos ya sea por que bloquee la sesión o simplemente la minimice, al querer retomar la misma no responde, se bloquea y me impide usarla, obligándome a cerrar la app (TaskManager) y ejecutarla nuevamente. La aplicación está hecha con C# .Net y corre en un Win11.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: pueden ser los controles o algo de tu programa... no tenemos forma de decirte que hacer sin saber muchisimo mas...

Comment: Si claro! Tan solo pretendo ideas generales por dónde empezar!